# Fourier transform in light of representation theory and irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to better frame the *Fourier Transform* in light of representation theory. The classical definition that I remember from the course I had attended many years ago is

\begin{align}\mathcal{F}: L^1(\mathbb{R}) &\rightarrow \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}) \\ f&\mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-2\pi i\xi x} \, dx\end{align}

where $\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of continuous functions which approach $0$ at $\pm \infty$.

Now, by reading here and there, I kinda got the intuition that $e^{-2\pi i \xi x}$ are the irreducible representations of the (locally-compact) group $(\mathbb{R},+)$ (not sure about it).

Why do we use them to define the Fourier transform?

Can anybody help me to fill this gap?

Comment: $e^{-2\pi \xi x}$ are characters (mappings into $S^1$). Characters of locally compact group form a Pontryagin dual group. Fourier transform is defined by mapping functions on the group to the functions on the dual group (take character and integrate w.r.t. Haar measure). In case of $\mathbb{R}$ the dual group is again $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Rybin Dmitry Excellent comment that you should transform into an answer.

Comment: Many thanks, I would appreciate you going more in detail as suggested by @Jean Marie

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/37021

Comment: Here http://users.metu.edu.tr/sozkap/513-2013/Steinberg.pdf (pp. 30) a character is defined as a mapping $\chi_\varphi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, why did you define it on $S^1$?

Comment: That’s just the image of the map. You can still take the codomain to be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: So the **image** of the map will be $S^1$, of course we can write its codomain to be $\mathbb{C}$..